# How to pass an integer as an argument in Shell function and retrieve it

Tags: bash, function, shell, arguments

I have a small function like this -

```
#! /bin/sh
function hey() {
    a=$1
    echo $a
}

x=2
hey x
```

As per my understanding it should print `2` but it is printing `x`. How to resolve it?

Comment: try this `hey "$x"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running you code in my bash (not sh) , it also prints x.
But if i change the last line to

```
hey $x
```

then it prints 2.